# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute

Tags: java, jar

I know this is a very common question, but I tried googling and got no helpful result.
I'm trying to make a jar out of my "Main.class" file (made in NetBeans, but I'm not trying to make the jar with it)

I ran this command:

```
D:\NetBeans\trovanum3\build\classes\trovanum3>jar cf trovanum.jar *.class
```

And a .jar file spawned in that folder. I thought that would've worked, but it won't run.

I tried opening the jar file with an archive opener and inside it are the "Main.class" file and a "META-INF" folder containing a file named "MANIFEST.MF"
The file contains this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-e` option of [jar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) to specify the entry point, i.e. the main class.  For example:

```
D:\NetBeans\trovanum3\build\classes> jar cfe trovanum.jar trovanum3.Main trovanum3\*.class
```

Saves fiddling with the manifest if that's all you need in there.  Note the working directory is **one up** from that quoted in your question.  Otherwise the Main class is created at the top-level in the jar, rather than in a directory that reflects the package in which it should reside.  `jar -tvf` should then show something like this:

```
  0 Thu Oct 21 22:34:30 BST 2010 META-INF/
 80 Thu Oct 21 22:34:30 BST 2010 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
488 Thu Oct 21 22:18:24 BST 2010 trovanum3/Main.class
```

> -e
>
> Sets entrypoint as the application
>   entry point for stand-alone
>   applications bundled into executable
>   jar file. The use of this option
>   creates or overrides the Main-Class
>   attribute value in the manifest file.
>   This option can be used during
>   creation of jar file or while updating
>   the jar file. This option specifies
>   the application entry point without
>   editing or creating the manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the Main-Class property in the manifest file: [Understanding the Manifest](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html).  This usually means you need to add the manifest file yourself instead of letting it be added automatically.

By the way you can always run your code without a manifest like this:

```
java -cp path/to/myJar.jar my.package.MyClass
```

The manifest is required when you want to run it like this:

```
java -jar path/to/myJar.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called well, anything really, but we'll call it manifest.txt

Open manifest.txt and type:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

then to create your jar, type

```
jar cfm trovanum.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

And it should run fine.

Comment: If main is in a package, then it will have to be package.to.main.Main . Don't include the .class suffix, and replace Main with your actual main class.

Comment: What he said. :-P BTW, just using NetBeans to make the jar is really easy, why don't you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the mainifest file.

Add an extra line so it says :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: Main
```

Make sure there is two newline characters at the end.

Update the jar file. You could either have edited the Manifest in the jar file with WinRAR, 7-zip, etc. or you could have deleted the original jar (after extracting and editing) then ran

```
jar -cmf MANIFEST.MF trovanum.jar *.class
```

Then it would use your newly modified manifest in the jar.

Comment: I did so, and I'm now getting this error: 
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.

Comment: @Gabriele: Replace "Main" in Leo's example with the fully-qualified classname of your Java file that contains the `main()` method that you want to run.  E.g. `Main-Class: mypackage.MyClass`

Comment: That's main(String[] args), but yes. I didn't mean Main, i meant insert-name-of-your-main-class-here.

Comment: Mm.. What should I put in exactly? I tried Main-Class: trovanum3.Main, but it didn't work. Here's a screenshot from NetBeans of the package and class names, I think they are the same I put in the manifest. http://bit.ly/b8tAdE

Comment: @Gabriele: You need to say more than "it didn't work."  Communicate with us.  What exactly happened?  Did your computer catch on fire?  Was there an error message of some kind?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the same error came up. I put in the package name.class name but it still wouldn't work. (same could not find main class error)

Answer (score 1):

Create executable jar( and not plain jar file). You get this option in eclipse while exporting jar file. I was facing same issue and it resolved once I created the executable jar.

Create batch file as :
java -jar "abc.jar"  ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Main-Class attribute in the manifest of your jar.  See the java tutorial link below for details.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html