# Cannot run my .jar file

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried double clicking it, I didn't get anything, I tried opening it in CMD, I got this:

no main manifest attribute, in MyRestaurant.jar

What should I do ? :(

Comment: have you tried "java -jar MyRestaurant.jar" in a shell?

Comment: You could start with a little [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991936/failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute).

Answer (score 5):

When you create a JAR you need to specify which class has the main method you want to run, this is done by adding a manifest.txt as a file to the jar you create. It seems thats the thing its missing.

Create a manifest.txt file, just add one line `Main-Class: ClassName` followed by enter and add that file when you create your jar.

ex. -jar -cvmf manifest.txt app.jar ClassName.class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans IDE, the first time you complied, choose `Run` then Netbeans will ask you the main class. From next time, you can just `Clean and Build`.